# Xcode 6: Create pure C++ OpenGL application bundle (.app) without using "Cocoa Application" template

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, opengl, xcode6

I'm trying to create a pure C++ OpenGL application bundle (.app) instead of a plain command-line executable. I'm trying to avoid directly using Obj-C or Cocoa, though I am using GLFW which requires linking with Cocoa.framework.

I was able to accomplish this by selecting the *Cocoa Application* template and gutting everything except Info.plist and replacing main.m with main.cpp, but going through that process is pretty annoying. Plus, could there be important project setting differences between the *Cocoa Application* and *Command Line Tool* templates that affect performance/binary size? Their build settings are pretty similar, so maybe I'm in the clear.

Anyway, I have a couple options:

1. Keep doing what I'm doing (works, but annoying)
2. Generate application bundle from *Command Line Application* template (nicer, but not sure if possible)

If the answer is 1, I'll probably end up creating a custom target template.

Answer (score 0):

For an `.app` you will always require some Objective-C as to be able to interact with the user you will have to use `AppKit`, which is an Objective-C framework.

However the answer is to simply rename all `.m` files to `.mm` and use Objective-C++ which seamlessly allows you to use both Objective-C and C++ in the same file, with very few restrictions.

However I am unsure how you integrate GLFW, as in order to get keyboard and and mouse events you need to call `glfwPollEvents()` in a loop, and this event processing and looping is at odds with the OSX runloop, so it might not be possible.  Doing a quick Google didn't show a solution to me, so it will require much more investigation.  You might be forced to forget about GLFW and use OpenGL from within the main view, and use AppKit for mouse/keyboard input.

Comment: I think GLFW handles all the plumbing because so far the game loop and mouse/keyboard input work fine without any Obj-C. I had to link with IOKit, CoreVideo, Cocoa, and Opengl frameworks though. Also, I removed "Main nib file base name" and "Principal class" from Info.plist, but I'm not sure that was necessary.